# Postfix virtual_transport vs mailbox_transport

Tags: postfix

Whats the difference between `mailbox_transport` key and `virtual_transport` key?

In old examples I've seen virtual_transport used but it did not seem to work on my Ubuntu 14.04 system, whereas mailbox_transport definitely does.

Is this a case of a changed api and looking at legacy/out-of-date examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mailbox_transport` is a transport for `local(8)`, while `virtual_transport` is the default delivery transport for virtual mailboxes.